# Understanding one usage of "in" keyword in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance

I'm trying to understand Kotlin take of generics especially with the `in` and `out` keywords. I've written this simple piece to hopefully illustrate my point of confusion.

This is the method that looks and works OK;

[image]

Here, IDE gives a hint saying that the type of the item the for loop is iterating over is a `Shape`. This is good.

Another version of the method above that doesn't seem quite right at first glance (since it's a "consumer"). But all I want to do is to read a list of shapes and that's all what's in this `from`.

[image]

That doesn't work which is maybe right according to the rules but I am not able to connect the dots here. It seems like a safe operation. I can also see Kotlin downs the type to "Any?" which explains why this gives a compiler error already. Can someone explain the potential type unsafety here please?

Comment: "Kotlin provides a complementary variance annotation: in. It makes a type parameter contravariant: it can only be consumed and never produced"

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks but I want to understand the reasoning behind it. Again, It looks like a safe operation to me. Or I'm wrong on this but in that case I really need to an example that visualise how this usage breaks type-safety dynamics of the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variance is always a tough concept to work through…

If you're using the terms ‘producer’ and ‘consumer’, note that they refer to your interaction with the item in question ‚ in this case, the `MutableList` parameter.

Your first function, with a `MutableList<out Shape>` parameter, can accept a list of `Shape`s, or a list of any subclass of `Shape`.  (`out` means roughly ‘or any subclass’.)

In each case, if you're consuming the list, whatever you pull out of the list will always be a `Shape` (as the IDE confirms).

But if you want to put something *into* the list (as a producer), you can't tell what would be safe to add, as that would depend on whether it's a subclass, and which one.

Your second function, with a `MutableList<in Shape>` parameter, is the opposite: it can accept a list of `Shape`s, or a list of any *superclass* of `Shape`.  (`in` means roughly ‘or any superclass’.)

In each case, it's always safe to put a `Shape` into the list (as a producer).  But you can't tell anything about the type of what you pull *out* of it (as a consumer): it could be called with a `MutableList<Any?>`, which could contain `String`s or `File`s or whatever.  So the compiler will give it the universal type, `Any?` (as the IDE confirms).

Comment: "Your second function, with a MutableList<in Shape> parameter, is the opposite: it can accept a list of Shapes, or a list of any superclass of Shape" - Having read your post, I exactly thought the same thing. So, you can pass a list of Any, or maybe list of Foo (assuming Shape extends a Foo class) through that parameter. None of them represent Shape objects which would break the type safety.